# Getting error in Entity Framework when trying to add an item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting the below error when trying to add an item to the database context. I'm using Entity Framework in a Web API project. The sample code is shown below.

Exception

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
>   HResult=0x80131501   Message=An error occurred while updating the
>   entries. See the inner exception for details.   Source=EntityFramework
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   WebApiSample.Controllers.OrdersController.Orders(Order neworder) in
>   C:\Repository\bitbucket\OtherProjects\WebApiSample\WebApiSample\Controllers\OrdersController.cs:line
>   173    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>
> Inner Exception 1: UpdateException: An error occurred while updating
>   the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception 2: SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'OrderNumber', table
>   'C:\REPOSITORY\BITBUCKET\OTHERPROJECTS\WEBAPISAMPLE\WEBAPISAMPLE\APP_DATA\DATA.MDF.dbo.Orders';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been
>   terminated.

This code is written in a POST method in Web API:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Orders(Order neworder)
{
    if (neworder == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = neworder.OrderNumber });

    try
    {
        using (OrderContext db = new OrderContext("ConnectionString"))
        {
            if (neworder == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Orders.Add(neworder);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return Created<Order>(uri, neworder);
}
```

The `Order` entity:

```
namespace WebApiSample.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

        public Decimal OrderAmount { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int OrderQty { get; set; }

        [Column("ShippingStatusFlag")]
        public string ShippingStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `OrderItems` entity:

```
namespace WebApiSample.Models
{
    [Table("OrderItems")]
    public class OrderItems
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Order")]
        [Column(Order =1)]
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        public int ItemSeq { get; set; }
        public Decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int ItemQty { get; set; }

        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The data is passed in the POST request body is

```
{
        "OrderNumber": 9000,
        "OrderAmount": 20,
        "OrderDate": "2018-01-15T00:00:00",
        "CustomerName": "TEST",
        "OrderQty": 3,
        "ShippingStatus": "N",
        "Items": [
            {
                "OrderNumber": 9000,
                "ItemID": 535,
                "ItemSeq": 1,
                "ItemPrice": 10,
                "ItemDescription": "Plantronics Bluetooth Headset",
                "ItemQty": 1,
                "order": null
            },
             {
                "OrderNumber": 9000,
                "ItemID": 536,
                "ItemSeq": 2,
                "ItemPrice": 5,
                "ItemDescription": "Yellow StickyNote 100ct",
                "ItemQty": 1,
                "order": null
            },
             {
                "OrderNumber": 9000,
                "ItemID": 601,
                "ItemSeq": 3,
                "ItemPrice": 5,
                "ItemDescription": "Black Think Permanent Marker",
                "ItemQty": 1,
                "order": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

What could be causing this issue? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the Message of Exception?

Comment: The exception I received is given on the top, first block quote

Comment: You have just shown the stack trace. Import the complete exception message in the question

Comment: As Chetan asked... what is the Exception Message? And also, what is the exception type and if it's `DbEntityValidationException`, then what is the content of `EntityValidationErrors`?

Comment: By the way, how about replacing `throw ex;` by `throw;`?

Comment: You're adding an `Order` to you Database. Are you sure you don't want to add an `OrderItem`? An `Order` would be added to the table `Orders` according to default-EF-naming. An `OrderItem` would be added to `OrderItems` because of the attribute `Table("OrderItems")`.

Comment: @grek40 I have update the exception details in the question now

Comment: which one is primary key? `OrderNumber`? In that case you have to use `AddOrUpdate`

Comment: Maybe you should set the attribute `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` for the `OrderNumber` property in class `Order`. There might be a mismatch between your model (expecting auto-increment keys) and your database/usage, expecting explicit key settings... or could the `OrderNumber` entry refer to an existing database row?

Comment: @kara: I'm adding Order and the Order items along with it, the OrderItems are in the Items list in the json.

Comment: @grek40: your solution of adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to the `OrderNumber` propety in class `Order` resolved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your `OrderNumber` property with the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`

```
public class Order
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Background: when a single integer property is marked as `Key`, the default setting is `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. With this setting, EF assumes that the database will take care of assigning a fresh primary key value. So for an entity with `Added` state, the key column will be ignored and not be transferred to the database.

This explains why the error is about a `NULL` value for a property that's not even nullable in code.